# Kernel panic after updating to linux kernel 3.8.0-32

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm getting the following errors after upgrading to the newest kernel:

```
VFS: Cannot open root device "UUID=1f09d896-51ad-47b8-8e62-c289906e527a" in unknown-block(0,0)
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
```

and

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

It allows me to boot if I change `root=/dev/sdc2`

I've tried re-installing the kernel as well running

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

and

```
sudo update-grub2
```

I've confirmed it's the correct UUID in the fstab etc.

```
# / was on /dev/sdc2 during installation UUID=1f09d896-51ad-47b8-8e62-c289906e527a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

I'm also able to boot from previous versions.  Google has pretty much run out of results for me to try now.  Help me askubutu, you're my only hope.

Comment: please use this `uname -r` and `uname -m` to your arch. Both should give the same value `64` or `32`...